# Why Mind is Fickle?

Tags: philosophy

Monkey mind
I don't think.
I live in present.
My mind always thinking.
Past thinking

Future thinking.

Hate thought..

Worry thought..

Pleasure thought..

Lust thought..

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the mind is dominated by attachment (greed), aversion (fear), and ignorance(curiosity). There are six mind doors with millions of objects. So the mind is continual scans (attention) these objects with a short span of time.
If you can keep your attention on only one object, it is called Jhana. Once you eliminated or suppressed attachment, aversion and ignorance then you can keep your attention on a neutral subject without mind fickle.

Answer (score 0):

Bhante Vimalaramasi talks about this in his talk about MN18
2015 Day 4 Easter Retreat 2 "Perceptions" MN18 - Bhante Vimalaramasi
Bhante discusses sutta MN18 from the majjhima nikaya on the subject of Perception. How perception leads to thinking and craving. Proliferations of mind.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1hNpff_JaA

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Master Junhong Lu's dharma talks -- [V 10-9 By Emptying your Mind completely, where do Contaminants settle?](https://www.4sage.org/post/v10-9):

> Don’t let your mind waver, in other words, you mustn’t casually desire for anything you see, as that means you have a wavering mind, and that usually spells trouble. You must understand that if you mind frequently allows itself to get distracted, then it means you don’t have control of it, and it’s easy for you to become defiled. The hardest thing to control is one’s own mind; if you can’t control it, then it’s easy for it to be dragged down by the karmic forces of other sentient beings.

... and ...

> Don’t involve yourself too deeply into all matters within the human realm. In other words, don’t be attached to anything in the human realm. If you constantly think that something must be like that, or something must be done by you, then you’ll be contaminated in the world. You must be in a state of emptiness to confront all afflictions. What is the state of emptiness? It’s to empty your mind; it’s not to have any expectations or thoughts about something. It’s to be devoid of hate or love. Nothing is there, and therefore it’s empty. As long as you use the state of emptiness to confront all afflictions, then your afflictions disappear. Your afflictions of today might disappear tomorrow.

Comment: Both your answers so far link to sites in a vaguely promotional manner. Please review [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: Thanks, what do you suggest how to post the quotations origin.

Comment: If it really is a quotation, make it clearer through the formatting and add your own commentary to explain why the quotation makes for an answer in this particular situation.

Comment: The ideal is, a) include a hyperlimk or reference to what you're quoting b) include a quote from whatever you link to or reference c) format the quote as a quote (using a `>` as [explained here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)). d) Maybe at least one sentence in your own words to say how the quote answers the OP's question. e) Advertising unrelated to the question (e.g. "Master Junhong Lu is the ambassador for peace in UN and UK in 2014") shouldn't be in the answer but you may include it in your user profile.

Comment: [Look here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/posts/38699/edit) too see how I formatted a quote using `>`, and a hyperlink using `[]` and `()`. You can also ulso use a blank/empty line to separate text into paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info.

Comment: I think he is asking why we have subconscious mind that lead to lust, worry, fear, etc and what is subconscious mind. I m interested to know also .

Answer (score 0):

Fickleness is a disease because the person having this disease will have difficult time understanding Dhamma. It can be cured by strictly following the Nobel eight fold path.
All the different thoughts will converge to love ,compassion and Dhamma.What is required is a commitment. But if fickleness has become a chronic disease then may be some medicines will be required to cure.Doctors can prescribe medicines. Being a monkey is not the disease. Inability to see the suffering is the real disease. Inability to develop a compassionate heart is the real disease.

> Why is mind fickle?

Mind is fickle because of past karma which was probably driven by some kind of greed.

Answer (score -1):

If you examine nature, much of nature is fickle -  volcanoes erupting, winds blowing, clouds forming, earthquakes, rain, flood, drought, etc. Then there are animals programmed to look for food & sex. Then there is growing, aging & passing. People are they same. Unless you believe in god and volitional-self-speculations of reincarnation, all life forms are similar. If you believe in Evolution, you understand you are descended from monkeys, gorillas, baboons and chimpanzees.

Comment: Nice example bro